# Unable to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter on case with list id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two fire object "chats" and "messages" like below. Each chat has list id of message.

```
"chats" : {
    "13dc0865-616b-4963-bfdf-6c9b5d2011ef" : {
      "buyer_id" : "dcf20b88-0612-4c13-933d-8b4f3d1838cb",
      "created_at" : 1500676108229,
      "item_id" : "fdab7447-e16d-4dac-8318-43f376ab3107",
      "key1" : "fdab7447-e16d-4dac-8318-43f376ab3107_7060e0b7-420b-48fd-bc02-2e4868c6c2bb_dcf20b88-0612-4c13-933d-8b4f3d1838cb",
      "key2" : "fdab7447-e16d-4dac-8318-43f376ab3107_dcf20b88-0612-4c13-933d-8b4f3d1838cb_7060e0b7-420b-48fd-bc02-2e4868c6c2bb",
      "message_ids" : [ "-KpbG1tnCItaKykzEjaN", "-KpbG3cvMwitf_yzdYb6", "-KpbG9UhiOBJFR8GPE2x" ],
      "seller_id" : "7060e0b7-420b-48fd-bc02-2e4868c6c2bb"
    },
    "25d667a3-6fe3-477d-b076-ac8d7b389133" : {
      "buyer_id" : "dcf20b88-0612-4c13-933d-8b4f3d1838cb",
      "created_at" : 1500674927785,
      "item_id" : "b3985467-4e4e-4ecf-a914-48fb66fc5225",
      "key1" : "b3985467-4e4e-4ecf-a914-48fb66fc5225_e68cf8f4-7470-45bf-8852-709d84fdae7f_dcf20b88-0612-4c13-933d-8b4f3d1838cb",
      "key2" : "b3985467-4e4e-4ecf-a914-48fb66fc5225_dcf20b88-0612-4c13-933d-8b4f3d1838cb_e68cf8f4-7470-45bf-8852-709d84fdae7f",
      "message_ids" : [ "-KpbBXhF5jjpspKgHPiV", "-KpbBpww9CcXL9n73J9j", "-KpbFgedT6RH2WZ6vjCV", "-KpbFxERv2adSRQHLnc2" ],
      "seller_id" : "e68cf8f4-7470-45bf-8852-709d84fdae7f"
    },

"messages" : {
    "-KpbBXhF5jjpspKgHPiV" : {
      "content" : "Tôi muốn mua Sua ban phim của bạn với giá 123.456 đ",
      "created_at" : 1500674927777,
      "sender_id" : "dcf20b88-0612-4c13-933d-8b4f3d1838cb"
    },
    "-KpbBpww9CcXL9n73J9j" : {
      "content" : "Tôi muốn mua Sua ban phim của bạn với giá 123.456 đ",
      "created_at" : 1500675006605,
      "sender_id" : "dcf20b88-0612-4c13-933d-8b4f3d1838cb"
    },
```

I am going to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to show **messages** for a chat conversation. My problem is on "**chat**" node, it only include the list message_id, the real data in inside node "messages".

How can I handle this case to work with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter ? (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

From the chat node `13dc0865-616b-4963-bfdf-6c9b5d2011ef`, you can access `message_ids` corresponding to it which are `-KpbG1tnCItaKykzEjaN, -KpbG3cvMwitf_yzdYb6, -KpbG9UhiOBJFR8GPE2x`.

Now you can get message data corresponding to the id as
(`messages` -> `-KpbG1tnCItaKykzEjaN` = `your message`). You can repeat this for remaining message ids.